# Opening dialogAPI from ribbon command crashes Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

After performing an action using a [Ribbon command](https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/5892) one may want to display a message using the [dialogAPI.](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui)

I noticed that, if the dialogAPI window is not closed by the end-user, when navigating to another email and clicking again the ribbon button Outlook crashes. This happens randomly, you may need to visit several emails and clicking the ribbon.

[image: Outlook Crashes]

This is annoying, one of the great aspect of the new office add-in model is its stability.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround or am I doing something wrong?

My config

**Outlook:** Outlook 2016 32 bits version 1611 (Build 7571.2072)

**Windows 10 Pro 64:** Version 1607 OSBuild 14393.447

Full add-in code for reproduction: 
https://github.com/bpatra/dialogapisample

Comment: Yes it is a bug. The team is looking into it. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: If you do not call `event.completed();` looks to avoid Outlook crashing

Comment: Is there an update regarding this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in Outlook build 16.0.7729.1000. Thanks for reporting!